# Rspec 'Subject' and 'let` not memoizing the value from block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I learned that `let` and `subject` should be memoizing the value from the block they've given and it will be lazy evaluation.

but when i run the following spec:

```
    describe "::build_stacks" do
        subject(:board) do
            Board.new(4,4)
        end

        it "should accept a number of stacks as an arg" do
            p board.object_id
            expect { Board::build_stacks(7) }.to_not raise_error
        end

        it "should return a 2D array containing the given number of empty stacks (subarrays of length 0)" do
            stacks_1 = Board::build_stacks(7)
            p board.object_id
```

I noticed the 2 object_ids printed are different. shouldn't they be different as the `:board` will be memoized?

Comment: _the 2 object_ids printed are different. shouldn't they be different_ Please restate your question.

Comment: @Huy Ha has the right answer

Answer (score 3):

Reference here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

The value from `let` will be cached across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.

Hope that help.